# parse reStructuredText README.rst to get description section

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools, restructuredtext

I seek to reuse information from my README.rst in package description of the setup.py

In my setup.py I have a readme function:

```
def readme():
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as f:
            return f.read()
    except (IOError, OSError):
        return ''
```

which I call in

```
setup(
    ...
    long_description=readme(),
    ...
)
```

Because my [reStructuredText](http://docs.python.org/devguide/documenting.html) is a rather huge [README.rst](https://raw.github.com/ewiger/mlab/master/README.rst) it might be a better way just to read only a particular section of restructured text.

Is there a smart way to rewrite `readme()` so that it parses README.rst and ignores the rest of reStructuredText formatting, i.e. gives only plain text of a small subsection?

Comment: Looking into reStructuredText parsing right now.. if I will figured it out - will post the answers.

Comment: Try [DocUtils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html#parsing-the-document). It's the rST parser used in Sphinx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use this part of DocUtils:

> "Parsing the Document
>
> The Parser analyzes the the input document and creates a node tree
>   representation. In this case we are using the reStructuredText parser
>   (docutils/parsers/rst/**init**.py). To see what that node tree looks
>   like, we call quicktest.py (which can be found in the tools/ directory
>   of the Docutils distribution) with our example file (test.txt) as
>   first parameter (Windows users might need to type python quicktest.py
>   test.txt):
>
> $ quicktest.py test.txt 
>       
>           My
>           
>               favorite
>            language is
>           
>               Python
>           .
>        Let us now examine the node tree:
>
> The top-level node is document. It has a source attribute whose value
>   is text.txt. There are two children: A paragraph node and a target
>   node. The paragraph in turn has children: A text node ("My "), an
>   emphasis node, a text node (" language is "), a reference node, and
>   again a Text node (".").
>
> These node types (document, paragraph, emphasis, etc.) are all defined
>   in docutils/nodes.py. The node types are internally arranged as a
>   class hierarchy (for example, both emphasis and reference have the
>   common superclass Inline). To get an overview of the node class
>   hierarchy, use epydoc (type epydoc nodes.py) and look at the class
>   hierarchy tree."
>     --http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/dev/hacking.html

to find just the nodes you need of the total document :) and then write only the relevant nodes

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with this, which is not perfect but does the job:

```
def readme():
    try:
        import docutils
    except ImportError:
        try:
            with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as f:
                return f.read()
        except (IOError, OSError):
            return ''
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'README.rst')) as f:
        document = docutils.core.publish_doctree(f.read())
        nodes = list(document)
        description = ''
        for node in nodes:
            if str(node).startswith('<topic classes="contents"'):
                break
            if type(node) is docutils.nodes.comment\
            or type(node) is docutils.nodes.title:
                continue
            description += node.astext() + '\n'
        return  return description.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
```

I would imagine one can do a much better and sophisticated parsing by walking the rST document tree.